# Using inotifywait (or alternative) to wait for rsync transfer to complete before running script?

Tags: bash, inotify, inotifywait

I would like to setup inotifywait so that it monitors a folder and when something is copied to this folder (lsyncd which uses rsync) I would like inotifywait to sit tight and wait until rsync is done before calling a script to process the new folder.

I have been researching online to see if someone is doing this but I am not finding much.

I'm not the most well versed with bash scripting though I understand some basics.

Here is a little script I found that pauses for a second but it still triggers a dozen events per transfer:

```
 EVENTS="CLOSE_WRITE,MOVED_TO"

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 cmd ..."
    exit -1;
fi

inotifywait -e "$EVENTS" -m -r --format '%:e %f' . | (
    WAITING="";
    while true; do
        LINE="";
        read -t 1 LINE;
        if test -z "$LINE"; then
            if test ! -z "$WAITING"; then
                    echo "CHANGE";
                    WAITING="";
            fi;
        else
            WAITING=1;
        fi;
    done) | (
    while true; do
        read TMP;
        echo $@
        $@
    done
)
```

I would be happy to provide more details or information.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no way to tell for sure when something is done writing to a file. It could just be paused. The best method is to have the process that creates the file write to a temporary name first, and then rename it to the real name when it's done. Then you can wait for the real name.

Comment: Use the `--partial-dir` option with `rsync` to write data to a separate directory, with files linked from there linked to their final destination once the transfer is complete.

Comment: if you're in a corporate environment, a well-understood solution is to send a separate 'flag' file after the main file is complete. You can include byte size, line-count, work-of-date, etc as a header line for further validation the file is a complete transfer. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what action you want to take, you may want to take a look at the tools provided by [Watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/).

There are two that might be most useful to you:

1. If you want to initiate some action after the files are synced up, you may want to try using [watchman-make](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-make.html).   This is most appropriate if the action is to run a tool like `make` where the tool itself will look over the tree and produce its output (in other words: where you don't need to pass the precise list of changed files directly to your tool).  You can have it run some other tool instead of make.  There is a `--settle` option that you can use to have it wait a few moments after the latest file change notification before executing your tool.

   `watchman-make --make='process-folder.sh' -p '**/*.*'`
2. [watchman-wait](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/watchman-wait.html) is more closely related to `inotifywait`.  It also waits for changes to settle before reporting files as changed, but because this tool doesn't coalesce multiple different file changes into a single event, the settle period is [configured as a property of the tree being watched](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/config.html#settle) rather than as a command line parameter

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of Watchman

Comment: Hi Wez, Thank you for the info. I think this should do the trick. I will read about it and give it a go. This is a personal project and I am not picky on what tool(s) are used. I will reply once I get further along.